# Output an array to HTML file

Tags: html, powershell

I have been given a working PowerShell script to modify. This script checks for broken links in a SharePoint web application and reports any broken links it finds. Currently, the script outputs the results to a text file.

**Code:**

```
$results | Out-File report.txt
```

**Result Format:**

> Name of link list - ID of the item - URL + URL Name - HTTP status code
>   - URL

**Result:**

> Link List 1 - 1 - http://google.com, Google (Good) - 200 -
>   http://google.com

---

However, when I try to use the `ConvertTo-HTML` function I get a different output:

**Code:**

```
$results | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File report.html
```

**Result:**

> 76

Therefore, instead of receiving a string of text I am receiving its length.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Note:**

- `results` is an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Convertto-Html` is not meant to be used like that, from  help:

Converts Microsoft .NET Framework objects into HTML that can be displayed in a Web browser.
You need to send an object (resulting from a command) to this cmdlet, not just a bunch of text. See: Get-Help Convertto-Html -Examples

this is a way to do what you want:

```
$results | ForEach-Object {Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Type NoteProperty -Name Value -Value $_; $_} | ConvertTo-Html -Property Value
```